# Unable to run azure function getting error as connection string not set

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have this `azure function` which should`read a message from service bus queue.`

I have already given connection string into code still throws error while running func -

```
Set the connection string named 'Endpoint=sb://demoser
vicebus2019.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKe
y;[Hidden Credential]' in the connectionStrings section of the .config file in t
he following format <add name="Endpoint=sb://demoservicebus2019.servicebus.windo
ws.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;[Hidden Credential]" conne
ctionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http|https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY
```

code- 
Function1.cs

```
 public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([QueueTrigger("customer", Connection = "Endpoint=sb://demoservicebus2019.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=text")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
```

local.setting.json

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "storageaccount-connectionstring",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "storageaccount-connectionstring"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So the connection property is the Key for the environment/configuration variable and not the actual connection string.

You can read about the bindings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---configuration)

> The name of an app setting that contains the Storage connection string to use for this binding

So change it to this:

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([QueueTrigger("customer", Connection = "MyConnection")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
    }
}
```

Configuration

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "storageaccount-connectionstring",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "storageaccount-connectionstring"
 "MyConnection":"Endpoint=sb://demoservicebus2019.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=text"
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm still getting this error [6/27/2019 8:17:48 AM] The following 1 functions are in error:
[6/27/2019 8:17:48 AM] Run: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
'Function1.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Failed to validate Microsoft Azur
e WebJobs SDK MyConnection connection string. The Microsoft Azure Storage accoun
t connection string is not formatted correctly. Please visit https://go.microsof
t.com/fwlink/?linkid=841340 for details about configuring Microsoft Azure Storag
e connection strings.

Comment: So that error is complaining about the format of your connection string. Make sure it's a valid format

Comment: i have used the same connection stirng which i get it from portal :(

Comment: Have you set any environment variables, since AFAIK Env Vars take precedence over the settings files?